# Excel giving wrong average

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

Hi I have an average function:

```
    =IF(ISERROR(AVERAGE(H6:H31)), "", AVERAGE(H6:H31))
```

but it returns the wrong average for the numbers: 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0

It produces 0.7 instead of 3.5 and I am definitely using column H row 6 to 31

What could cause this? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Average is considered as

Grand Total / Total no of Obs.

In this case you have total of 10 observations.

so, 7/10 is 0.7

Answer (score 7):

0.7 is the correct answer. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=average%20of%200%2C%200%2C%203%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%204%2C%200)

You are looking for the average excluding zeros. In which case you should use the AVERAGEIF function. In your case that would be:

```
=AVERAGEIF(H6:H31,"<>0")
```

This will give you 3.5

Comment: Nice. I didn't know there was an `AVERAGEIF` function.

Answer (score 0):

as said above. Excel is correct. This should get you what you want though:

```
=SUMIF(H6:H31, "<>0")/COUNTIF(H6:H31, "<>0")
```

Comment: I hadn't realised there was an `AVERAGEIF` function built into Excel as Donal has posted below. I would personally use his instead of mine.